# Database mining, Auto Graph and email at certain time of the day

Tags: sql, database, excel, ms-access, automation

I have some automated machines running a Pasteurization process, sensors register values such as Temperature, time, pressure etc...

Our main control software does offers us a historic graph for such values, however its not possible to mail them. The software is able to log all the data into an Microsoft Access/ SQL database. For the company, our days start at 6am so a 24/hr period is meant to start again at 6 everyday.

**Now the question:**
Is there a way to mine the database (can choose either) to graph all the values from 6am last day to 6am current day (X,Y plot) Automatically in Excel, and have it Automatically sent to some mail recipients EVERY day at 6 AM?

If so, how can I do this?

Comment: To be honest I don't really know. My knowlegge about the system is, the software logs everything into the database. I guess It should be bossible to filter the data as you mentioned. But what then, and how do I make this step and the following to be done automatically everyday at 6. Considering we are dealing with: Access, Excel and Outlook or any mailing form in the process

Comment: Time and Date is on a column by its own, we are able to filter the data for the day. I don't know how to run the Query on it's own, nor how would excel take ONLY this queried Data and work with it so it can be then sent via email.

Comment: Hmmm this is a really Clever solution @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister, could I use some help from you? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get Excel to query the Access database (if the email recipients are in your LAN), so when you refresh the query (or you can get it do refresh automatically when you open the spreadsheet) it fetches the relevant information for the day only. So no emails would be necessary, as you always use the same spreadsheet.

To do this, first open your access database and create a view (query) to fetch the data you need (use this as a reference to get today's or yesterday's data: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Examples-of-using-dates-as-criteria-in-Access-queries-aea83b3b-46eb-43dd-8689-5fc961f21762).

Then follow this tutorial to fetch the data from your view into excel: http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/import-access-data.html

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful! Worked like a Charm!